# Getting a value from for-loop?

Tags: java

i want to get all num values and print in to (......) but i couldnt do that. can u please help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int operands,num;
    int q=1;
    int a=0;

    do 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of operands (in range 2-10):");
        operands=keyboard.nextInt();            
    } while ((operands<2) || (operands>10));

    for (int number=1; number<=operands; number++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter number "+number+":");
        num=keyboard.nextInt();
        q=q*num;
    }

    System.out.print("Multiplication of numbers "+(.......)+" is: "+q);
```

Comment: you'll have to be more specific than that.

Comment: Enter the number of operands (in range 2-10):
3
Enter number 1:
20
Enter number 2:
30
Enter number 3:
10
Multiplication of numbers  is: 6000 this is is the output but i expect that Multiplication of numbers 20 30 10 is: 6000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an additional String variable you declare before the loop:

```
String numbers=" ";
```

and add to it in the loop body:

```
numbers += num+" ";
```

then print out this string in the place of (.......)

Answer (score 2):

I like FranzKnut answer but if performance is an issue, and even if it isn't, then please consider using a string builder instead.

Before the loop use

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("my numbers are: ");
```

Inside the loop add the following code.

```
sb.append(num);
```

Then at the end of loop you have something like

```
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: what is the way that i can get that numbers one by one. not in order

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a String into the program and concat with the new added numbers. Finally print string where you have to print.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int operands, num;
    int q = 1;
    int a = 0;
    String s = " ";
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of operands (in range 2-10):");
        operands = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while ((operands < 2) || (operands > 10));


    for (int number = 0; number <= operands - 1; number++) {
        System.out.println("Enter number " + number + ":");
        num = keyboard.nextInt();
        s = s + num;
        q = q * num;
    }



    System.out.print("Multiplication of" + s + " numbers is: " + q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok here you got

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int operands,num;
        int q=1;
        int a=0;
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int newNumbers = 1;

        do 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of operands (in range 2-10):");
            operands=keyboard.nextInt();        

        } while ((operands<2) || (operands>10));

        for (int number=1; number<=operands; number++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number "+number+":");
            num=keyboard.nextInt();
            q=q*num;
            numbers.add(num);
        }
        StringBuilder newTextNumber = new StringBuilder("");
        for(Integer s: numbers){
            newTextNumber.append(s).append(" ");
            newNumbers *= s;
        }


        System.out.print("Multiplication of numbers "+newTextNumber+" is: "+newNumbers);
     }
}

Enter the number of operands (in range 2-10):
3
Enter number 1:
20
Enter number 2:
30
Enter number 3:
10
Multiplication of numbers 20 30 10  is: 6000
```

Comment: what is the way that i can get that numbers one by one. not in order

Comment: for(Integer s: numbers){
            newTextNumber.append(s).append(" ");
            newNumbers *= s;
        }